# Opposite Borel subgroups of $SL(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The subgroup of all upper triangular matrices of $SL(n)$ is a borel subgroup, $B$. Does this Borel subgroup have an opposite Borel subgroup? Is it the set of all lower triangular matrices?

Given a borel subgroup $B_+$, a borel subgroup $B_-$ is said to be an opposite Borel subgroup if $B_+ \cap B_-$ is a maximal torus.

Also, is $[B,B]$ the set of all upper triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal?

Thank you very much for your time, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: _Containing_ a maximal torus is too weak a condition, since any conjugate of the Borel by a Weyl group element would produce another Borel with that property...

Comment: oops. edited my question. Thank you for your insights, you seem knowledgeable on the subject at hand.

Comment: @Hakuna: yes, it has an opposite Borel given by the lower triangular matrices, and yes, $[B, B]$ is the set of upper triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal.